# How to use XXD in java

Tags: java, linux, terminal

If I run
`echo 'E4:C8:C1:51:1A:58:1E:A6:0A:DF:E0:59:CA:4E:60:66:0B:36:0F:24:EA:76:93:39:61:F7:79:60:B2:2F:DE:B6' | xxd -r -p | openssl base64` in the terminal It will print `5MjBURpYHqYK3+BZyk5gZgs2DyTqdpM5Yfd5YLIv3rY=`. How do I achieve the same result using java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the `String` on the colon delimiter. Parse each hexadecimal digit into a `byte[]` and then base64 encode that array of bytes.

```
String s = "E4:C8:C1:51:1A:58:1E:A6:0A:DF:E0:59:CA:4E:60:66:0B:36:"
    + "0F:24:EA:76:93:39:61:F7:79:60:B2:2F:DE:B6";
String[] split = s.split(":");
byte[] arr = new byte[split.length];
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(split[i], 16);
}
String o = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(arr);
System.out.println(o);
```

Outputs

```
5MjBURpYHqYK3+BZyk5gZgs2DyTqdpM5Yfd5YLIv3rY=
```

Comment: But if the data is more than 48 bytes `openssl base64` (without `-A` cap) inserts linebreaks while Java `Base64.getEncoder()` does not. Using `.getMimeEncoder()` _may_ be close enough (it breaks every 76 chars per RFC1521/2045 while `openssl` breaks every 64 per RFC1421).